# app crash when i click push notification

Tags: swift, apple-push-notifications, crashlytics

I have a webservice response in a dictionary and I sort it by date and display it in a tableview(X viewcontroller). When the push notification is clicked I will redirect it to the above mentioned(X) viewcontroller. but app got crashed when I click on the notification. Can someone help me out with the below crash log?

```
Exception name: EXC_BAD_ACCESS / KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE
1 CoreFoundation_CFStringCheckAndGetCharacters + 80812
2 CoreFoundation-[__NSCFString getCharacters:range:] + 80720
3 CoreFoundation isEqualToString + 1255332
4 CoreFoundation-[__NSSingleEntryDictionaryI objectForKey:] + 889612
5 Appname 4304500692 + 1521620 
6 Appname 4304499340 + 1520268
7 Appname 4304580448 + 1601376
78 UIKit -[UIApplication _handleNonLaunchSpecificActions:forScene:withTransitionContext:completion:] + 2640488
79 UIKit __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke + 13195140
80 UIKit-[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 13194848
81 UIKit__125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke + 10498760
82 UIKit_performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 12174280
83 UIKit -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:] + 10498424
84 UIKit-[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 8288092
85 UIKit-[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 6853284
86 FrontBoardServices __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.362 + 52384
87 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_client_callout + 6672
88 libdispatch.dylib _dispatch_block_invoke_direct$VARIANT$mp + 37372
89 FrontBoardServices __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 264180
90 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 263320
91 FrontBoardServices -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 264756
92CoreFoundation__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 964472
93 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 964344
94 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 962432
95 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun + 953176
96 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 35924
97 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal + 44928
98 UIKit UIApplicationMain + 472512
99 Appname 4303008020 + 28948
100 libdyld.dylib start + 5480
```

In Appdelegate :

```
 func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {

    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ALERTHANDLER"), object: nil)
     completionHandler()
}
```

in a viewcontroller:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    // response action
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.methodOfReceivedNotification), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "ALERTHANDLER"), object: nil)
}

@objc func methodOfReceivedNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    let storyBoard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "MenuStoryboard", bundle: nil)
    let newViewController1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ViewController")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(newViewController1, animated: true)
}

override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Can you show me push notification dictionary data here ?

Comment: Have you checked does your notification method get calls? Remote notification receiving delegate is `didReceiveRemoteNotification`.

Comment: @TheTiger yes changed. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment below method will help you to fix you problem.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
   NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: its not happening all the time. its a random crash.why is that?

Comment: @Bharathi Then crash is somewhere else. Might be in `ViewController` class.

Comment: You are right it will crash randomly what is happing your case when you are moving to other view controller from "ViewController" observer deallocated and bottom of the line it got crashed while push received.

Comment: so i want to remove the above method?

Comment: Yes, you should check with making changes.